# Passing div id as a parameter to the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I want to pass the id of a div to the controller. i have attached an actionlink to the div and I am trying to do something like below,

index view of my TasksController

```
@Html.ActionLink("c", "Create", "TasksController", new { i = 6 }, new { @class = "element" })
```

inside the Create controller

```
public ActionResult Create(string i)
        {
            ViewData["I"] = i;
            return View();
        }
```

and then in Create View,

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("divID", ViewData["I"])
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.divID)
</div>
```

but this is not working.
Any help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refrain from putting tag names in the title, that is what the tags are for - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("c", "Create", "Tasks", new { i = "6" }, new { @class = "element" })
```

**You can solve this problem by configuring your routing too:**

global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",     // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

The Actionlink:

```
Html.ActionLink(article.Title, 
                "Item",   // <-- ActionMethod
                "Login",  // <-- Controller Name.
                new { "6"}, // <-- Route arguments.
                null  // <-- htmlArguments .. which are none. You need this value
                      //     otherwise you call the WRONG method ...
                      //     (refer to comments, below).
                )
```

The Link will look like this:

```
<a href="/Item/Login/6">Title</a>
```

**Please consider that the controllers name is "Tasks" not "Taskscontroller".**

**Edit:**
For redirecting to another View and passing some data you have to use "RedirectToAction" in the controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("Tests", new { 
   ID = "6", 

});
```

**Edit**

you have to write **"6"** and just **Tasks** hope this will work!

Comment: Thank you but it seems I have not asked the question correct way. I want this value "6" to be sent to another view as ViewData like I have mentioned in the original post. * I want someway to send data from a view to another view via a controller. For example: the clicked div's id.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I wanted. It's like this, I have a index view with a lot of divs and once i click on it I use action link to pass the clicked element's id to the controller using,    @Html.ActionLink("c", "Create", "Tasks", new { i = "6" }, new { @class = "element" })
then I want this id to be passed to create action of the same controller. I am trying to do this as mentioned in the original post but not woking. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: @KasunLak Have you tried to give a constant string to the ViewData: ViewData["I"] = "Test"; Do you see test in the Textbox?

Comment: Yes, I did and it's getting displayed.

Comment: @KasunLak You've debuged your solution until now? Is there any content in ID? Do you have tried the routiung changes? And do you have changed the Controllers name inside Actionlink? Can you post how your hyperlink code looks like (pure HTML)?

Comment: Yes when I debug 'i' is null in the create action. But here is how the hyperlink looks like.    <a class="element" href="/Tasks/Create?i=6">c</a>